# In ng-repeat track by $index

Tags: angularjs

I have an array in which suppose 5 values are present example (1,2,3,4,5);
now after performing some operation with this array now my array becomes (1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)now i want to use ng-repeat with $index and want that duplicate data will be shown only one time.Is is possible?

Comment: Do you want to show only 1,2,3,4,5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a custom filter to remove duplicates from list. it can be something like below

```
app.filter('unique', function() {

  return function(list) {

    var unique = function(origArr) {
      var newArr = [],
          origLen = origArr.length,
          found, x, y;

      for (x = 0; x < origLen; x++) {
          found = undefined;
          for (y = 0; y < newArr.length; y++) {
              if (origArr[x] === newArr[y]) {
                  found = true;
                  break;
              }
          }
          if (!found) {
              newArr.push(origArr[x]);
          }
      }
      return newArr;
    };

    return unique(list);

  }

});
```

and then use it with ng-repeat

```
<p ng-repeat="item in list | unique">List Item: {{ item }}</p>
```

please refer to this plnkr example https://plnkr.co/edit/wklSOYJpHZxFlzCNPI9L?p=preview

Comment: Thanks working fine....

Answer (score 1):

Just create a angular filter gets the unique items - [JSFiddle Reference](https://jsfiddle.net/ku8yr9g5/)

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
});

app.filter("uniqueItem", function() {
  return function(collection) {
    var output = [];
    angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      if (output.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        output.push(item);
      }
    });
    return output;
  };
});

<div ng-repeat="item in items | uniqueItem">List Item: {{ item }}</div>
```